Poder elegir id de una tabla al insertar
Tengo una tabla productos en la que introduzco registros sin indicar el id, ya que ese campo es autoincremento.
Pero me gustaría dejar vacíos algunos espacios por si necesito insertar alguno más en otro momento.
Lógicamente, si hago la inserción en Phpmyadmin puedo elegir el id, pero si lo hago desde mi web conectada a mysql en localhost, no sé cómo conseguirlo.

Ninguna base de datos te deja apartar campos incrementales, la solución la debes plantear desde otro punto de vista, la cual puede ser tener un campo propio de identificación del producto el cual puedes insertar el valor que quieras.

Estas planteando mal el concepto. No importa el orden autoincremental de los productos, este es útil para uso interno (joins, FK, etc) y para que la aplicación sepa que registro modificar, eliminar, etc. Para el usuario debes tener criterios para ordenar en otras columnas, como tipo producto, departamento, el nombre alfabético, el código, la fecha de modificación, etc

Pon en tu consulta el valor del campo a insertar, que ahora no lo debes estar haciendo y el mysql lo agrega por ti al ser incremental. Pero piensa que si es el valor más alto de ese campo, los siguientes registros insertados que no tengan el valor del campo incremental preestablecido continuaran a partir de ese.  No se yo para que lo quieres incremental en ese caso.

Pero cual sería la gracia o "lógica" de dejar unos IDs reservados?? Osea, en el futuro vas a querer que un producto SI o SI tenga el ID 333?? Lo veo innecesario y buscar problemas donde no los hay

Si temgo varias categorias de productos y cada una se introduce en un tramo de números, puede que al añadir posteriormente un producto de una categoria, lo quieras poner con los productos de su categoria.

Para eso tienen SU CATEGORÍA. Si quieres tener todo por separado le puedes poner un número o código que lo identifique según lo que quieras o cada categoría en una tabla separada. Pero repito, es hacer problemas donde no los hay

Parece que todavía no entiendes como crear una base de datos relacional. Crea una tabla de categorías con su id_categoria. Crea una tabla de productos que también tiene una columna id_categoria y dala una clave externa que asegura que la id_categoria en la tabla de productos existe en la tabla de categorías. Así cada producto está asignado una categoría.

Ya tengo la solución.
Adjudicar a cada registro un código de producto, tipo PR00001...
Y ahí sí que puedo darle el número que quiera.

EH? pero porque?? no estan asociados a un producto??? para que tienen que tener un codigo que particularmente diga que tipo de producto es??? hay una logica que no vemos atras de esto???

Esta solución te la ha propuesto @AlbertoMarun. Estaria bien que lo mencionaras en tu respuesta para que se lleve el crédito al menos.  No es una mala solución, es la lógica en tu escenario, pero no responde a tu pregunta, la cual estaba mal pensada porque lo tenias mal entendido. Los ID autoincrementales no tienen porque corresponderse con los código de producto reales, pueden ser simplemente campos de índice que se usan cuando se hacen operaciones con ellos, para identificarlos de forma única. Recomendación: Establece un índice único en ese nuevo campo para no duplicarlos sin querer.

¡Esto no responde a la pregunta!  Y es probablemente porque el título de la pregunta está mal planteado.  Pero, básicamente preguntas, ¿cómo hacer una ensalada de papas? y respondes ¡perfecto, voy a hacer una ensalada de brócoli!.
